# How to use mapbox "case" expresion on nested properties?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

How to use nested value in order to use case == operator? Something like:

```
this.map.setPaintProperty("somelayer", "fill-color",
        ["case",
          ["==", ["properties:some_prop"], someval],
          "#34c0dd",
          "#499bbc"]
```

where properties is dict:

```
properties = {
some_prop: 1,
some_prop2: 2,
// and so on
}
```

I have tried `["properties.some_prop"`] and `["properties"]["some_prop"]` and that does not work as well.

And how to print that mapbox query like console.log or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `properties` is just the regular `properties` field on a GeoJSON object, then you don't mention it explicitly - all those fields are just accessed directly:

```
this.map.setPaintProperty("somelayer", "fill-color",
    ["case",
        ["==",  ["get", "some_prop"], someval], "#34c0dd",
         "#499bbc"
    ]);
```

Assuming `#499bbc` is the default colour you want.